# Android Studio or Eclipse working with maven/gradle

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, gradle

I would like to make progress in development of android mobile distributed systems. It would cover introducing TDD with continuous integration and especially support for maven/gradle. It would be good to make all robust.

Regards

The question is (regarding further specs), what would be the most suitable IDE choice. I know mostly it is the matter of a personal pros and cons. But the aim is to be robust and support automaticity during development. So no personal factors.

Comment: So, what is your question? :)

Comment: Whatever your actual question: I cannot recommend Eclipse with maven for Android development. Eclipse/Android is fine, and Eclipse/maven is probably as well, but about 6 months ago I spent a few weeks trying to get all 3 to work together and while it did work intermittently it was anything but robust...

Answer (score 2):

An IDE is a personal preference. However the support for Maven and Gradle is definitely better with Android Studio. 
Google supports both IDE's for Android development. I personally prefer Android Studio as the integration is better. Navigation to Android specific resources (for example R.string.myvalue) is just a link in Android Studio. Such a navigation often lacks in Eclipse.

From: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html (for Android Studio 0.8.14)
[image]

Comment: In Eclipse ADT there is also on click navigation to R resources

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Android Studio. It has Gradle support which is better than the solution of Eclipse. 
By the way Android Studio will be the official IDE soon.